# how can I toggle classes in my list menu only on the selected item?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I need to build a `list-menu` with a `hover` effect. I want to `toggle` a class containnig several other classes. This generally works, but I have the problem that the toggle-effect is switching the class on all list items in my list menu and not only on the one I select by hovering.

I made a fiddle to show you.

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rheingau360/NcQsd/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("li a").hover(function() {
    $(".lvl3-hover").toggle();

})
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to filter only the elements that are under the one receiving the hover event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".lvl3-hover").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give the hover to direct child `'>'` of event holder:

try this:

```
$("li a").hover(function () {
    $("> .lvl3-hover", this).toggle();
});
```